# Play each audio element individually using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, audio

I have multiple `<audio>` elements in an HTML page. The problem is that the jQuery script plays all of the audio together and I need it to play them individually.

I deployed it so you can have a better understanding: https://suspicious-williams-5196e6.netlify.app/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-bl" style="display: inline;">
  <a href="#" title="Listen to the song" class="player-controls">
    <span class="play"></span>
    <span class="pause"></span>
  </a>
  <audio id="player">
    <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/t32waag3ib20b28/OneDance-Drake.mp3?raw=1" type="audio/mp3">
  </audio>
</div>
```

```js
var getaudio = $('#player')[0],
  mouseovertimer,
  audiostatus = 'off',
  playerControls = ".player-controls";

$(document).on('click touch', playerControls, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$(playerControls).hasClass("playing")) {
    if (audiostatus == 'off') {
      $(playerControls).addClass('playing');
      getaudio.load();
      getaudio.play();
      window.clearTimeout(mouseovertimer);
      audiostatus = 'on';
      return false;
    } else if (audiostatus == 'on') {
      $(playerControls).addClass('playing');
      getaudio.play();
    }
  } else if ($(playerControls).hasClass("playing")) {
    getaudio.pause();
    $(playerControls).removeClass('playing');
    window.clearTimeout(mouseovertimer);
    audiostatus = 'on';
  }
  return false;
});

$('#player').on('ended', function() {
  $(playerControls).removeClass('playing');
  audiostatus = 'off';
});
```

```css
.player-controls {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 1.25em;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 1.75em;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.player-controls .play,
.player-controls .pause {
  display: block;
  background: url("images/play.svg?raw=1") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 1.75em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.75em;
  z-index: 5;
}

.player-controls .play::before,
.player-controls .pause::before,
.player-controls .play::after,
.player-controls .pause::after {
  -webkit-border-radius: 1000px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1000px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.75em;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1.75em;
  z-index: 0;
}

.player-controls .play::before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.player-controls .pause {
  background-image: url("images/pause.svg?raw=1");
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.player-controls.playing .play {
  opacity: 0;
}

.player-controls.playing .pause {
  opacity: 1;
}

.player-controls:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: The HTML shown on this site only shows one set of "player controls" and one `audio` element.  Please show how you are including multiple audio elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize the sibling selector using jquery like this while selecting the audio element.

```js
var mouseovertimer,
    audiostatus = 'off',
    playerControls = ".player-controls";
    
    $(document).on('click touch', playerControls, function(e) {
    var getaudio = $(this).siblings('audio');
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(this).hasClass("playing")) {
        if(audiostatus == 'off') {
            $(this).addClass('playing');
            getaudio[0].load();
            getaudio[0].play();
            window.clearTimeout(mouseovertimer);
            audiostatus = 'on';
            return false;
        } else if(audiostatus == 'on') {
            $(this).addClass('playing');
            getaudio[0].play();
        }
      } else if($(this).hasClass("playing")) {
        getaudio[0].pause();
        $(this).removeClass('playing');
        window.clearTimeout(mouseovertimer);
        audiostatus = 'on';
      }
      return false;
    });
    $('#player').on('ended', function() {
    $(playerControls).removeClass('playing');
    audiostatus = 'off';
    });
```

Try replacing the jquery code with above one.

Changes I have made in your code:

- I have moved down the `getaudio` instantiation inside event listener.
- Also while instantiating it make sure you use it like this:
  `var getaudio = $(this).siblings('audio');`

And also remove the id from all the `<audio>` tags, since they are duplicate doesn't really serve any purpose!

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a reproducible code here?

Comment: Nevermind I updated the answer, I tested this one on your website itself, please check the updated answer